# how to install rails snippets for emacs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I have installed yasnippet. I would like to add rails snippets to it.

I have found this repo - https://github.com/eschulte/yasnippets-rails. How do I include it for the rails snippets to show up?

Also the above repo was last updated before 3 yrs. Is there any more recent snippets repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me. Download and extract the archive provided by github in your `.emacs.d/my_plugins` and add this line in your `.emacs` :

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/my_plugins/eschulte-yasnippets-rails-9b12c79")`

Then eval-current-buffer and you should see a bunch of new snippets in the menu.
My advice would be not to learn them, but to get inspired by them and create your own set.

Comment: Thanks. How do I view all the available snippets and the ones added by the above repo ?

Comment: It is as simple as clicking in the menu bar : YASnippet->ruby-mode, or going to explore this package !

Comment: Thanks again! Two questions - 1) I have to turn on the menu by M-x menu-bar-mode, how do I load it by default ? 2) The YaSnippet menu shows up the first time the menu bar comes up, however after I move to another buffer and back, I cant see the menu anymore ! How do I get it back.

Comment: You already know by the other question, just put `(menu-bar-mode 1)` in your .emacs (kind of surprising, usually it is on by default and we ask to turn it off, no ?) I don't know for the disappearing menu.